# What's wrong with strndup?

Tags: c, macos, flex-lexer

I'm writing a parser using flex. I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.7.
I have already include header files like this:

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
```

but it says

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_strndup", referenced from:
      _yylex in ccl2332A.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

why?

Comment: Note that Mac OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite) provides `strndup()` — and also `strnlen()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is no method strndup in string.h or stdlib.h, try using strdup() which is probably what you want. If you really need to specifiy the length you want allocated you could do it using malloc and memcpy instead.

Comment: that's not completely correct - [`strndup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strndup.html) is "standard", but that standard is not implemented widely (yet). It's been present in GLIBC as an extension for quite a while. (But +1 anyway, malloc + strcpy is a good workaround.)

Comment: Note that if you want `strndup`-like behavior, you should use `memchr` (searching for a null byte in `n` bytes) to find the length, add 1, `malloc` that, and then `memcpy` and finally add the null terminator. There's never a need to use `strncpy`.

Comment: `strndup()` is coming to C2x: see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2478.pdf

Answer (score 4):

`strndup` is a GNU extension and is not present on Mac OS X. You will have to either not use it or supply some implementation, like [this one](http://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5575.11/libiberty/strndup.c).

Comment: @R.. OS X 10.6 was certified as fully compliant POSIX 2003. It was released only three months after FreeBSD added an implementation of `stndup`. I think it's forgivable to not have pulled in a whole new kernel revision right before going gold. I believe 10.7 had this function.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a strndup implementation, you can use this one.

```
char *strndup(char *str, int chars)
{
    char *buffer;
    int n;

    buffer = (char *) malloc(chars +1);
    if (buffer)
    {
        for (n = 0; ((n < chars) && (str[n] != 0)) ; n++) buffer[n] = str[n];
        buffer[n] = 0;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned Upon on stack Overflow, so you might want to add that "here is an implementation of `strndup` for those platforms that do not have it". BTW the size (`chars`) argument to `strndup` is of type `size_t`, which is distinct from `int`.