# 'strndup' not defined in this scope

Tags: c, mingw, zeromq

I'm trying to compile libzqm on windows using MinGW (GCC 4.8). Compilation terminates with this error:

```
'strndup' was not declared in this scope
```

So, `strndup` should be in `string.h` right? I tried to add `/mingw/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include` to `CXXFLAGS` but didn't work.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Don't you mean strndup?

Comment: You shouldn't count on it being there anyway. It's not a standard function.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo (too localized).


Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062822/whats-wrong-with-strndup

Comment: @H2CO3 No that's not a typo. the typo happened when I was typing error in SO. The source code uses `strndup` while it seems not provided within mingw distro.

Comment: @H2CO3 it isn't. according to a comment made by OP on my (now deleted) answer, the lib he's using won't compile because it can't find strndup.

Comment: Note that `strdup` is also not defined by the C standard, though it is defined by POSIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

before

```
#include <string.h>
```

`strndup` is not standard C but if you use GNU libc, then you do get it by including the extensions as above.

Comment: As `strndup()` is part of the current POSIX standard, compiling with at least `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` would also do.